# INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session. Session not found

Tags: webservices, c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using SFDC_DATAUPLOAD.Importservice;
using SFDC_DATAUPLOAD.enterprise;


namespace SFDC_DATAUPLOAD
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string username = "user@gmail.com";
            string password = "password";
            SforceService sforce = null;
            LoginResult logres = new LoginResult();
            sforce = new SforceService();
            logres = sforce.login(username, password);


            PG_ImportWebServiceService dataup = new PG_ImportWebServiceService();
            dataup.SessionHeaderValue = new SFDC_DATAUPLOAD.Importservice.SessionHeader();
            dataup.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = logres.sessionId;
            //dataup.Url = logres.serverUrl;


            CustomerHierarchy c = new CustomerHierarchy();
            c.country = "France";
            c.descr = "TestDescription";
            c.key = "1";
            c.status = "CREATE";
            dataup.createCustomerHierarchy(c);

        }
    }
}
```

In this code , 
                I have used two wsdl one is Enterprise.wsdl and another one is Impoertservice.wsdl. while creating connection with salesforce i am getting ERROR Invalid session Id. If i add that commented line that is service url, i'm getting error No operation available for this request. kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You definitely need to use the server url returned from the LoginResult in addition to the session id. Is createCustomerHierarchy() defined in the same org that you are getting the session for?

Comment: Create customerHierarchy is defined in ImportService.wdsl

Comment: I'm getting the session ID from Enterprise.wsdl file and assign it to the Importservice.wsdl

Answer (score 3):

The endpoint URL from the login result will be for the Enterprise WSDL. It will be something like:

> https://na2.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/32.0/0DF40000000001

Note the `/c/` that indicates it is for the Enterprise WSDL. You will need to change that part as per the `soap:address` `location` defined in ImportService.wdsl.

From one of my Apex classes with web service methods the endpoint URL was:

> https://na5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/**XYZ**/**TestClass**

where XYZ was the namespace and TestClass was the name of the hosting Apex class.

---

Based on your comment, you will want something like:

```
dataup.Url = 'https://cs17.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/ImportService';
```

You should verify this against the URL that appears at the end of the Importservice.wsdl to check that the class name is correct. For example, do you have a namespace defined that needs to be included in the URL.

Ideally you would take this a step further and use the domain returned by the login result with the constant path for the Apex class. That way it will work if you connect to an org on a different pod, such as a sandbox.

Comment: yes,  service url contains /c/  "https://cs17.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/33.0/00Dg00000005zFt/0DFg00000008PLK" and help me to solve this.

Comment: It sounds to me that you might be using session Id obtained from an org and using it in combination with another org's serverurl or vice versa. Is importservice.wsdl a custom web service contract or a Salesforce artifact?

Comment: Will not all this URL stuff be handled automatically by a developer library of the corresponding language?

Comment: @Meglio I don't see how it could unless it was explicitly coded for the differences between the Enterprise WSDL and an Apex Web Service. Maybe when the apex web service wsdl is imported the endpoint will be correctly set. It would depend on the language and what Salesforce pods are involved.

Comment: @DanielBallinger, so, if I instantiate a partner client and do some operations and then need to call an Apex Web Service, it won't be enough to just copy the same session header? I mean, will I also need to detect the correct url to make a call to the Apex Web Service and assign it first before making a call? UPD. I'm currently creating a new client instance based on the exported wsdl file of the Apex Web Service, then copying the same session header. It works for the same account used for wsdl export, but not for the other accounts. I wonder if the issue is with a URL?

Comment: Apex wsdls are per org, if you're using Apex WSDL generated from org A to call orgB you'll need to do the dance to fix up the destination URL.

Comment: @Meglio As I mentioned about different hosting pods and superfell mentioned about different orgs, If you are moving the connection around you may need to alter the URLs. Maybe ask a new question if you are still having issues.